# MySQL Find similar strings

Tags: mysql

I have an InnoDB database table of 12 character codes which often need to be entered by a user.
Occasionally, a user will enter the code incorrectly (for example typing a lower case L instead of a 1 etc).
I'm trying to write a query that will find similar codes to the one they have entered but using LIKE '%code%' gives me way too many results, many of which contain only one matching character.

Is there a way to perform a more detailed check?

Edit - Case sensitive not required.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: do u want case sensitive check??

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [`soundex`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex).  Commonly misspelled strings have the same soundex code, so you can query for:

```
where soundex(Code) like soundex(UserInput)
```

Comment: this is not successfull bcoz Two strings that sound almost the same should have identical soundex strings.` `A standard soundex string is four characters long, but the SOUNDEX() function returns an arbitrarily long string. You can use SUBSTRING() on the result to get a standard soundex string. All nonalphabetic characters in str are ignored. All international alphabetic characters outside the A-Z range are treated as vowels.`

Answer (score -1):

use without  wildcard `%` for that

```
SELECT `code` FROM table where code  LIKE 'user_input'
```

thi wil also check the space

```
SELECT 'a' = 'a ', return 1  whereas SELCET 'a' LIKE 'a ' return 0
```

[reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Comment: -1 This will find only "code" and nothing else; the question is to find similiar strings

Comment: @Andomar, user wants to check the user input with given code in db, see my update.